# can I write Swift to bind UI stuffs in iOS by id

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I am learning iOS developing by Swift.
I have some experience about Android development so I am super curios about   :
Can I binding UI stuffs(etc button, label) by programable typing the id which I did in Android instead of using drag and drop

I have search couple key words in google but not finding some suitable answer.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I would recommend this method, but you can assign tags to the UI elements and then link them in code by using `viewWithTag` to find the view: `button = self.view.viewWithTag(15) as! UIButton`.

Comment: Please don’t do this, use IBOutlet to connect object from your UI to your code

Comment: `viewWithTag` is actually no binding, though follow the advice from @Marcel and @vacawama and don't do that.

Comment: check this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag

Comment: Using tags is a bad practice. Please, don't recommend them to a beginner. There is no good reason to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. When I am learning iOS development, I can't stop to compare how I did in Android development.  Including page navigation , I am not a big fan of using drag-and-drop to binding ui to controllers. :P 
But I would never use the answer in developing , thanks for all the answers and comments again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your view to the storyboard or xib, at the utilities panel on the right select Show the Attributes inspector. Add numeric tag to your view just like the photo below.

[image: Button with tag]

Now in your view controller, you can get the view reference by using this code.

```
let button = self.view.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes is it possible but it is not a recommended way, anyway you can use the tag property, and then you can refer to your UI object as:

```
if let myLabel = self.view.viewWithTag(120) as? UILabel {
    myLabel.text = "some text"
}
```

Comment: Although this will work, this is not a good way to do it. Processing becomes expensive if there are too many subview. Not to mention identifying using tags will become confusing.

Comment: Sure, I’m totally agree with you, I just answered that is possible.